# 400 bad request php

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Хочу отправить запрос, на создание поста в группе вк, вчера буквально работал, сейчас выдает 400 bad request.
Самое главное, что если вывожу переменную на экран, вставляю в адресную строку, то все срабатывает.

```
$url2 = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=".$params["group_id"]."&from_group=".$params["from_group"]."&message=".$message."&v=".$params["v"]."&access_token=".$params["access_token"];
echo $url2;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$r = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Все дело было в переменной `$message`
Вид её такой: `$message = "New post on group wall";`
Видимо просто пробелы не конвертировались. Потому что без пробелов, запрос проходил.
По этому, я попросту добавил вот такую строку:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "message= $message");
```

Вот собственно и все.
Вчера работало, потому что я отправлял запрос без пробелов.
Почему это сработало, и почему возникала проблема из за пробелов, я объяснить не могу. Сам не достаточно знаю curl :)